# WatchOS Complication not updating automatically

Tags: swift, watchos

I'm trying to get my watchOS complication to automatically update every few minutes. In the ComplicationCOntroller.swift, I setup the complication in the getCurrentTimelineEntry() function, and it works the first time, but only updates the value displayed in the complication if I launch the WatchOS app. Can I set my complication to automatically update in the background? Even if it's a set time interval, e.g. "update in 3 minutes". Here's my ExtensionDelegate:

```
import WatchKit
import WatchConnectivity

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, WCSessionDelegate {

let session = WCSession.default
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let server = CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()

override init() {
    super.init()

    WKInterfaceDevice.current().isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true

    session.delegate = self
    session.activate()
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    print("Session started on \(WKInterfaceDevice.current().name)")
    defaults.set("32", forKey: "PhoneBatteryLevel")

}

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
    print("Received application context: \(applicationContext["PhoneBatteryLevel"]!)")
    defaults.set(applicationContext["PhoneBatteryLevel"], forKey: "PhoneBatteryLevel")

    for complication in server.activeComplications! {
        server.reloadTimeline(for: complication)
        print("Reloading complications...")
    }
}


func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    // Perform any final initialization of your application.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillResignActive() {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, etc.
}

func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
    // Sent when the system needs to launch the application in the background to process tasks. Tasks arrive in a set, so loop through and process each one.
    for task in backgroundTasks {
        // Use a switch statement to check the task type
        switch task {
        case let backgroundTask as WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the background task once you’re done.
            backgroundTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        case let snapshotTask as WKSnapshotRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Snapshot tasks have a unique completion call, make sure to set your expiration date
            snapshotTask.setTaskCompleted(restoredDefaultState: true, estimatedSnapshotExpiration: Date.distantFuture, userInfo: nil)
        case let connectivityTask as WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the connectivity task once you’re done.
            connectivityTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        case let urlSessionTask as WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the URL session task once you’re done.
            urlSessionTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        case let relevantShortcutTask as WKRelevantShortcutRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the relevant-shortcut task once you're done.
            relevantShortcutTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        case let intentDidRunTask as WKIntentDidRunRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the intent-did-run task once you're done.
            intentDidRunTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        default:
            // make sure to complete unhandled task types
            task.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        }
    }
  }

}
```

And the relevant ComplicationController code:

```
func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
    switch complication.family {
    case .modularSmall:
        let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallSimpleText()
        template.textProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "\(defaults.integer(forKey: "PhoneBatteryLevel"))")
        template.tintColor = UIColor.yellow

        let entry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
        handler(entry)


    case .modularLarge:
        let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody()
        template.headerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Battery Levels")
        template.headerTextProvider.tintColor = UIColor.green
        template.body1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "iPhone: \(defaults.integer(forKey: "PhoneBatteryLevel"))%")
        template.body2TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Watch: \(getWatchBatteryLevel())%")

        let entry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
        handler(entry)

    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you solve the problem?